# Many users getting email notification from Salesforce for expiring self-signed Certificate. How to prevent and manage?

Tags: user, certification, push-notification

We are having a self-signed certificate in our org which is being used for integration with SAP. It works based on two-way SSL with certificate authentication. It is going to expire in few days.

**Issue**:

Many users in our org getting email notification from Salesforce (noreply@salesforce.com) mentioning the expiring certification.

**Question**:

Is that possible to restrict the email notifications to few users rather than all users? Is there a place in Salesforce where I can manage the users that should get email notifications? Please advice. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Any users with Modify All Data and View Setup and configuration perms, along with all the system administrators in the org will receive these email notifications. Currently, there is an idea to restrict this distribution to limited users.

Comment: Here is a link to the Idea: https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000E7JQQA0